# PyTorch object detection tutorial problem (can't run training)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, faster-rcnn

I'm working with Mask RCNN neural network and with PyTorch, I need to load dataset, and I followed this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html I have coordinates of polygon bounding box of every word on image wrote in JSON file. So now, I don't know how to compute rectangle bounding box of that polygon coordinates.
I'm using `train_labels.json` from ArT (ICDAR2019) dataset.
I think the problem is somewhere about appending x and y coordinates to `boxes` but can't figure out. :

```
f = open('train_labels.json')
data = json.load(f)
boxes = []
for i in data.keys():
    for j in data[i]:
        mask = j['points'] # --> polygonBB coordinates
        obj_ids = np.unique(mask)
        obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

        num_objs = len(obj_ids)
```

Variable `mask` has polygon bb coordinates.

When I use:

```
left, right = min(mask, key=lambda p: p[0]), max(mask, key=lambda p: p[0])
top, bottom = min(mask, key=lambda p: p[1]), max(mask, key=lambda p: p[1])    

boxes.append([left[0],top[1],right[0],bottom[1]])
```

then the output is
`ValueError: All bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invalid box [24.994787216186523, 472.875732421875, 46.65693664550781, 472.875732421875] for target at index 0.`

For some reason, the second and the last coordinate is the same but why?

But if I use the code from PyTorch tutorial:

```
for z in range(num_objs):
    pos = np.where(masks[z])
    xmin = np.min(pos[1])
    xmax = np.max(pos[1])
    ymin = np.min(pos[0])
    ymax = np.max(pos[0])
    boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
target = {}
target["boxes"] = boxes
```

Output is:
`ValueError: All bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invalid box [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] for target at index 0.`

My annotation for word "red" is:

```
 {
                "transcription": "red",
                "language": "Latin",
                "illegibility": false,
                "points": [
                    [
                        21.51514273595292,
                        96.10111281287746
                    ],
                    [
                        34.41549485283264,
                        97.283756254127
                    ],
                    [
                        36.42017833821299,
                        98.51023290725634
                    ],
                    [
                        48.266909960703956,
                        99.59706074137782
                    ],
                    [
                        51.456108522323206,
                        92.58403315228024
                    ],
                    [
                        63.3249196091766,
                        93.6674491203431
                    ],
                    [
                        60.960257769931985,
                        110.16062344395255
                    ],
                    [
                        49.094275907517556,
                        109.06503983039966
                    ],
                    [
                        46.79115225196064,
                        109.89584392001012
                    ],
                    [
                        34.94618448639528,
                        108.80142524223687
                    ],
                    [
                        32.794444829218214,
                        108.60261473324032
                    ],
                    [
                        19.896204045991865,
                        107.41087863881067
                    ],
                    [
                        21.51514273595292,
                        96.10111281287746
                    ]
                ]
            }
```

This is just one word of I don't know how many, I have 80k images with random generated words. I'm also sending a image with some other text but all text instances are equal annotated.

Also I have and this code and the output is:

```
if len(mask) == 0:
    raise ValueError("Can't compute bounding box of empty list")
minx, miny = float("inf"), float("inf")
maxx, maxy = float("-inf"), float("-inf")
for x, y in mask:
    # Set min coords
    if x <minx:
        minx = x
    if y <miny:
        miny = y
    # Set max coords
    if x >maxx:
        maxx = x
    elif y > maxy:
        maxy = y
boxes.append([minx,miny,maxx,maxy])
```

`ValueError: All bounding boxes should have positive height and width. Found invalid box [594.2897338867188, 533.2000122070312, 366.35723876953125, 468.6328125] for target at index 0.`

Comment: Have you done the sanity checks? I would check that p[0] and p[1] are correct. and also that youre top/bottom/left/right indexes are also correct. And finally double check that you are operating on (y:y,x:x) pixel coordinate (for cv2) if you are using cv2. Note your last error fails because you still have minx>maxx and miny > maxy hence negative height and width.

Comment: I tried to print `print([left[0],top[1],right[0],bottom[1]])` and output is: [615, 937, 634, 963][222, 108, 254, 124] -> I think it is ok.
Also I print `print([minx,miny,maxx,maxy])` and output is:  [168, 123, 277, 161]
[179, 235, 343, 264] -> I think it is ok. 
And if I print `print(xmin, xmax,ymin,ymax)` from for loop, output is:  1 1 0 0, 1 1 3 3, 0 0 4 4, 1 1 6 6, 0 0 0 0, 1 1 0 0 -> I don't know what are these numbers.

Comment: So you find some ghost numbers. That should imply there is something wrong, perhaps there are edge cases in your json. Are all three steps failing on the same image? Very difficult to debug with this. I mean quite literally the reason for each of the 3 method failing is as explained in the error text. 1) height = 0, 2) h,w = 0, 3) -ve height and width. So something must be feeding the wrong info here. For the third slice, consider min < x <= max. min < x < max is breaking at the edge.

Comment: Ok tnx, I'll try change some condition.